# Match color between 10 cameras

Tags: camera, multi-camera

I will need to film on 10 cameras soon, as I can't afford to rent 10 cameras, I will collect them from friends, which means I will have many diffrent cameras.

Should I try to color match them in camera with internal saturation, contrast and sharpness or should I match them in post?

They are all lower quality cameras like Canon 700D, Nikon D3500, Panasonic G70...

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you can do to mitigate your pain in post is to white balance all of them on the day of the shoot in the conditions of the shoot (shoot lighting, etc), probably right before the shoot. And then get to work in post. Don't hope for a miracle though. No one would use that many cameras and hope for the colors to match.
You're only going to be reduce the imperfections, so embrace them and don't lose your mind over matching everything perfectly 'cause it's technically impossible -- too many cameras and too many models.